# how to validate email with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an input form which asks the user to enter its username and password. once the user enters the data, and clicks the submit button , the jquery will run a post request and send the information to the controller /Home/RegisterUser, but all im getting is

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in email2.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

for some reason the ajax request is not able to obtain the values email and password, as they are set to null ie  email = null.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="email2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"  >
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <fieldset style="width: 200px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Text="Email Address"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCreateAccount" runat="server" Text="Signup" OnClientClick="Signup();return false;" />
    </div>

        <div id="postResult">?</div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>

// use  PageMethods. if want to use methods within WebForm1.apsx.cs

<%--<script type="text/javascript">
    function Signup() {
        var email = document.getElementById('<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>').value;

        PageMethods.RegisterUser(email, password, onSucess, onError);

        function onSucess(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        function onError(result) {
            alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
        }
    }
</script>--%>

<%--<script type="text/javascript">


    var url = "/Home/RegisterUser";

    var email = document.getElementById('<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>').value;

    var f = $("form1");
    var url = f.attr("action");
    var formData = f.serialize();
    $.post(url, formData, function (data) {
        $("#postResult").html(data);
    });


</script>
--%>

<script type="text/javascript">


    var username = $("input#txtEmail").val();
    var password = $("input#txtPassword").val();


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnCreateAccount").click(function () {
            debugger;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Home/RegisterUser',
                data: { username: username, password: password },
                ContentType: 'application/Json',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Register succesfully");
                    $("#postResult").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error while registration");

                }
            });
        });
    });




    </script>
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
//need this to run  [WebMethod]
using System.Web.Services;

namespace email2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }


        [WebMethod]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public ActionResult RegisterUser(string email, string password)
        {
            string result = "Congratulations!!! your account has been created.";
            if (email.Length == 0)//Zero length check
            {
                result = "Email Address cannot be blank";
            }
            else if (!email.Contains(".") || !email.Contains("@")) //some other basic checks
            {
                result = "Not a valid email address";
            }
            else if (!email.Contains(".") || !email.Contains("@")) //some other basic checks
            {
                result = "Not a valid email address";
            }

            else if (password.Length == 0)
            {
                result = "Password cannot be blank";
            }
            else if (password.Length < 5)
            {
                result = "Password canonot be less than 5 chars";
            }

            return Content(result);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: isnt there any way i can extract the email from the form  ? I tried string email = Request["txtEmail"]; string email = Request.Form ["txtEmail"] and string email = Request.QueryString["txtEmail"]; within the controller but none of them worked

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
public ActionResult RegisterUser(string email, string password) 
{
    string result = "Yeah!";
    //... some checks

    return Content(result);
}
```

instead of

```
public static string  RegisterUser(string email, string password) 
{
    //....
}
```

Your Action can't be found if it's a `static`